# Exclude text between two words in a single line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a text like this one:

```
23660291|2019-12-23T23:13:24.380000|44.0108|11.3048|9.7|SURVEY-INGV||||ML|1.4|--|5 km E Barberino di Mugello (FI)

23610441|2019-12-17T03:40:08.660000|44.0317|11.2825|9.9|SURVEY-INGV||||ML|1.0|--|5 km NE Barberino di Mugello (FI)

23610371|2019-12-17T02:42:40.600000|44.0283|11.2798|9.8|SURVEY-INGV||||ML|1.4|--|4 km NE Barberino di Mugello (FI)

23609901|2019-12-17T00:19:33.840000|44.0362|11.2713|7.6|SURVEY-INGV||||ML|0.6|--|5 km NE Barberino di Mugello (FI)

23596801|2019-12-14T21:47:53.240000|44.0172|11.3043|9.3|SURVEY-INGV||||ML|1.8|--|5 km E Barberino di Mugello (FI)
```

It goes on, but the layout is the same

and I need to exclude text in order to get only some columns, a text like this

```
2019-12-23T23:13:24.380000|SURVEY-INGV|1.4|--|5 km E Barberino di Mugello (FI)
```

I've tried a lot of times but I'm stuck. Could anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: grep -v + unwanted word but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm a newbie so I don't know what to do

Comment: You can get the desired output with ``echo "2019-12-23T23:13:24.380000|SURVEY-INGV|1.4|--|5 km E Barberino di Mugello (FI)"``.  If you want a solution that’s based on the input, please *explain* the relationship between the input and the output, and, ideally, give a few more examples.  In particular, (1) Do you want the 2nd, 6th and 11th-13th fields, whatever they are, or do you want the text between `23660291|` and `|44.0108`, the text between `9.7|` and the next `|`, and the text after `ML|`? … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) Do you want the second line, or the first non-blank line, or the line(s) that contain `23660291`?  (3) Or do you really want output from all five lines, but you showed us only that one?  (4) And what’s the deal with the blank lines? … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I have edited the text to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is the exact text then this will work:

```
awk -F "|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"} NR==1 {print $2,$6,$11,$12,$13}' file.txt
```

The first part sets the input field separator as the pipe which is `|` with `awk -F "|"`. Then, it prints that field separator between each field or column as you want in your output `BEGIN{OFS="|"}`. It then prints those specific columns from the first line or record `NR==1 {print $2,$6,$11,$12,$13}' file.txt`.

The output:

```
2019-12-23T23:13:24.380000|SURVEY-INGV|1.4|--|5 km E Barberino di Mugello (FI)
```

Answer (score 2):

At least with GNU `cut`, either

```
cut -d '|' -f 2,6,11-13 text
```

or

```
cut -d '|' --complement -f 1,3-5,7-10 text
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "s/\|\{2,\}/|/g" filename| awk '$0 !~/^$/'|awk -F "|" 'OFS="|"{print $2,$6,$8,$9,$10}'
```

output

```
2019-12-23T23:13:24.380000|SURVEY-INGV|1.4|--|5 km E Barberino di Mugello (FI)
2019-12-17T03:40:08.660000|SURVEY-INGV|1.0|--|5 km NE Barberino di Mugello (FI)
2019-12-17T02:42:40.600000|SURVEY-INGV|1.4|--|4 km NE Barberino di Mugello (FI)
2019-12-17T00:19:33.840000|SURVEY-INGV|0.6|--|5 km NE Barberino di Mugello (FI)
2019-12-14T21:47:53.240000|SURVEY-INGV|1.8|--|5 km E Barberino di Mugello (FI)
```